# Copy document library - Document set to other Site

Tags: powershell, document-set, copy-and-paste

I need to copy document library to other site via powershell.

My structure of this document library is like this:

In a root si many folder, these folders can contains subfolder and these subfolder can contains next subfolder.

In each folder/subfolder can be a file (usually PDF) or a document set.

I found a script which recursively passes every folder and copy every item to the new site.

I have a problem that this script copy a Document set like a folder.

How Can I modify these script to store the structure - folder will be folder, Document Set will be Document Set?

I didn't find anything helpful :( I would like to store the all metadata :)

Thank you

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   #Variables for Processing

    $SourceWeb = "SourceSite"

   $TargetWeb = "TargetSite"

   $web1 = Get-SPWeb $SourceWeb

   $web2 = Get-SPWeb $TargetWeb


    $SourceLibrary = "SourceDocumentLibrary"

    $TargetLibrary = "TargetDocumentLibrary"

   $SourceFolder = $web1.GetFolder($SourceLibrary)

   $TargetFolder = $web2.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)

    #Call the Function to Copy All Files
    Copy-Files $SourceFolder $TargetFolder

    #Custom Function to Copy Files from Source Folder to Target
    Function Copy-Files($SourceFolder, $TargetFolder)
    {
    write-host "Copying Files from:$($SourceFolder.URL) to $($TargetFolder.URL)"
    #Get Each File from the Source
    $SourceFilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files

    #Iterate through each item from the source
    Foreach($SourceFile in $SourceFilesColl)
    {
        #Copy File from the Source
        $NewFile = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($SourceFile.Name,  $SourceFile.OpenBinary(),$True)

        #Copy Meta-Data from Source
        Foreach($Field in $SourceFile.Item.Fields)
        {
            If(!$Field.ReadOnlyField)
            {
                if($NewFile.Item.Fields.ContainsField($Field.InternalName))
                {
                    $NewFile.Item[$Field.InternalName] =      $SourceFile.Item[$Field.InternalName]
                }
            }
        }
        #Update
        $NewFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()

        Write-host "Copied File:"$SourceFile.Name
    }

    #Process SubFolders
    Foreach($SubFolder in $SourceFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
        {
            #Check if Sub-Folder exists in the Target Library!
            $NewTargetFolder = $TargetFolder.ParentWeb.GetFolder($SubFolder.Name)

            if ($NewTargetFolder.Exists -eq $false)
            {
                #Create a Folder

                $NewTargetFolder = $TargetFolder.SubFolders.Add($SubFolder.Name)

            }
            #Call the function recursively
            Copy-Files $SubFolder $NewTargetFolder
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with document set you need to use the Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets dll. This [TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-CopyMove-1946d2af) has very good example how to copy move the document sets.